# HTML Email Gmail ignoring style paddings and margins

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to send a html email to my app clients. I have designed the following styled code, which work fine in my browser. But, for some reasons, some of the styles are ignored by Gmail.

I have commented some of them that seems to be ignored, all of them margins and paddings.

Why is that? How can I solve this issue?

PD: I am testing on safari browser, and Gmail app on iOS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
      *,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        padding: 10px; /* IGNORED */
      }
      h2 {
        font-family: "Arial", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        line-height: 26.4px;
      }
      p,
      a {
        font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 20px;
      }
      a {
        color: slategray;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      hr {
        height: 1px;
        margin: 10px 0px; /* IGNORED */
        border: none;
        background-color: silver;
      }
      header {
        border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
        padding: 10px;  /* IGNORED */
      }
      main {
        padding: 20px;  /* IGNORED */
      }
      footer {
        border-top: 1px solid silver;
        padding: 10px;  /* IGNORED */
      }
      footer p {
        font-size: 11px;
        margin: 3px 0px;
        color: silver;
      }
      footer a {
        font-size: 11px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="white">
    <header>
      <img
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/The_Boring_Company_Logo.svg/1024px-The_Boring_Company_Logo.svg.png"
        height="50px"
        alt="TBC"
      />
    </header>

    <main>
      <h2>Hi, Emma</h2>
      <br />
      <p>We welcome you to our platform, ...</p>
      <br />
      <p>
        Are you ready to start a new path in your life with our service? ...
      </p>
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>All the best,</p>
      <p>The Boring Company.</p>
    </main>

    <footer>
      <p>Please do not reply to this email. ...</p>
      <p><a href="#">OC</a> | &copy; All rights reserved</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to put inline style (`style` attribute on the DOM with wanted style)

Comment: If you are creating a html mail template or send html mail then use inline styling not style. Tag to style the elements !

Answer (score 0):

Try with:
margin-top, margin-bottom, margin-left, margin-right, padding-top, padding-bottom, padding-left, padding-right